# How should display the hover over help in samrtphones for website

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone, mouseevent

I have the website where i have the form for searching. and i have the `title` tag on the icon where when user hovers mouse then they see the help text there.

It works fine in PC but don't work in smartphones.

how should i display help for `iphones` etc

```
<span title ="This is the help text" class="icon-question-sign"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover is not really for mobile devices. You can use touch events so when the user touches the icon it will display the help text. If the touch event is being used for something else, say a link maybe, then you could implement a long touch.

```
$('.icon-question-sign').on('touchstart', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: any idea  , how can i do that in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to get any sort of hover or mouseover effect on a mobile device. Perhaps you could change it to be a clickable button instead when viewed from mobile devices?